# VBA Saving PDF issue

Tags: excel, vba

I need to save around 300 pdf files but every 20-30 files. I have to press "Cancel" for the file to continue saving or else the macro does not keep running. This image will explain better my situation :

[image: Problem picture]

```
'Saving PDF FILE
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False

                Workbooks(Nom_Fichier_Model_MMS_ON).ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, _
                Filename:=Path_CRM & site_oper & "_" & "4" & num_Canal_Dist & "_" & anneeFisc & ".pdf"

                site_oper = Application.WorksheetFunction.Rept("0", 10 - Len(site_oper)) & site_oper

                Workbooks(Nom_Fichier_Model_MMS_ON).ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, _
                Filename:=Path_Sharepoint & site_oper & "_" & num_Client & "_MarginReport_312_" & anneeFisc & ".pdf"
```

Comment: Is there a loop that you have not included in your code snippet?

Comment: Please post the full macro or at least the full part which shows your loop.